# Raspberry Pi 4B(4GB) yellow lightning bolt

Tags: boot-issues

1. I had connected Beagle Bone black to USB3 of Raspberry Pi 4B(4GB) and ran putty to peek into Beagle Bone black.
2. Then I sent shutdown command from putty of raspberry Pi to beagle-bone black and later shutdown my RPi4.
3. Now after few hours when i switched on my RPi4 i saw the yellow lightning bolt icon on right top and my sd card contents corrupt
4. So i switched switch off and switch ON, no display on HDMI
5. I removed the SD card, changed the power supply (5.18V/3A) and only connected power supply and HDMI, i got the startup message on
   screen.
   measured voltage at TP1 (around 4.7V)
6. Now i connected mouse and inserted USB pen-drive with OS installed
7. Switched On RPi4B, the board booted, voltage at TP1 dropped to 4.6V, with yellow lightning bolt on right top corner, and red LED went OFF
8. Since im still getting the yellwo bolt icon, I removed the USB c cable and provided 5.18Vdc at GPIO pin 2 and GND on Pin 6
9. With multi-meter connected, I switched ON RPi4
10. The System boots, RED led goes ON -OFF intermittently, I get the raspbian desktop but with yellow bolt icon.
11. Voltage at GPIO2 shows between 5.10 to 5.16Vdc

Why is the yellow bolt icon flashing (RED led OFF-ON-OFF-ON...) in-spite of voltage around 5.15V?
could it be some problem in my RPi4 power supply section?

Comment: Why ask us to guess?  Disconnect as much as possible and see if the voltage is okay.  Add things back in to the voltage falls.

Comment: Buy the official psu

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I have given 5.14V on GPIO pin 2 and GND on GPIO pin 6. Still when the system boots, RED led goes ON -OFF in between and i get yellow lightning icon on my monitor. While the system is booting Im monitoring the supply on multi-meter. The voltage moves between 5.10 to 5.15V, but still yellow bolt and red led is not steady

Comment: A multimeter cannot in general show short dips in the measured voltage. It is not an appropriate tool. You need an oscilloscope.

Comment: Yes, correct short dips will not be observed on meter. I also doubt the current delivered by my PSU is not more than 2A